# CCSpriteBatchNode changes opacity of frame - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

When I add a sprite to my scene from

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     @"b.plist"];

    bspriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"b.png"];

    [self addChild:bspriteSheet z:-1];
```

the opacity of the sprite is lighter than it was originally and the images look fine in "b.png". Does anyone know why it is doing this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I think.You have set a z-index to -1.Just check it by changing z value to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly because it's z-index is behind another view which is then somehow masking it. Try changing the z-index to 0 or 1 and see if that works.